# How can I upgrade an old iMac from 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, imac, snow-leopard, upgrade

```
Model: iMac11,2 (Core i3-550, MC509LL/A)
```

It was shipped with Snow Leopard 10.6.4, and I managed to update to 10.6.8 via Apple Software Update. After some research I found that this old iMac is capable of running Sierra (10.12.x) and made a few attempts to upgrade.

I noticed that I must first upgrade it to Lion (10.7.5) or El Capitan (10.11.6), both of which are no longer available from the Mac App Store.

But, all info I found from Google tells me to upgrade via MAS. (That's why I'm adding a month in the title.) Any ideas?

Comment: You can try going into an Apple Store where they can download it for you.  Barring that, you can have a friend make a USB installer for you if they have El Cap or Sierra already installed.

Comment: Try this link to download El Capitan:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options you can try:

- [Download  El Capitan from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12)
- Take your Mac into an [Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/retail/) where they can download and install El Capitan for you.